# CSS relative positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a web page with dynamic dimensions i.e I first read the size of the canvas and adjust my elements widths and heights accordingly.

```
if(!window.JSFX)
    JSFX=new Object();

if(!JSFX.Browser)
    JSFX.Browser = new Object();

if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape") != -1)
{
    JSFX.Browser.getCanvasWidth = function() {return innerWidth;}
    JSFX.Browser.getCanvasHeight    = function() {return innerHeight;}
}
else    if(document.all)    {
    JSFX.Browser.getCanvasWidth = function() {return document.body.clientWidth;}
    JSFX.Browser.getCanvasHeight    = function() {return document.body.clientHeight;}
}

function f(){
var h = JSFX.Browser.getCanvasHeight();
var w = JSFX.Browser.getCanvasWidth();
var elem1 = document.getElementById("left");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("right");

if(h){
elem1.style.height = (h-115)+"px";
elem2.style.height = (h-95)+"px";
elem2.style.width = (w-305)+"px";
} 
else return false; 
 } 

window.onload = f;
```

// The HTML

```
<div id="container">
           <div id="left">
           </div>

           <div id="right">
           </div> 
</div>
```

My problem is that when I resize the window the divs jump all over the place. I need help with CSS and JavaScript I can use to make the divs resizable when the window is resized.

Thanks.

Comment: acceptance is key, my friend, so please accept some answers

Comment: Its a css issue - all i want is to keep 100% height and width  without my elements moving. 
example - http://www.yell.com/maps/MapAction.do

Comment: Accept some answers first before seeking anymore help

Comment: How does this work? Do i have to go to old questions and mark them?

Comment: Yup: pick your favourite answer to each question you’ve asked, and click the big tick on the left of it. (I see you’ve done this already, just thought I’d note it here for others.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"position:absolute"
and/or
"position:fixed"

Answer (score 0):

I think the `window` object has a `resize` event that fires when the user resizes their browser.

So, maybe add this at the end of your JavaScript code:

```
window.onresize = f;
```